# How to make unwrap optional to be elegant in swift3

Tags: swift

```
guard let value = notification.userInfo?[Notification.BLEKey.value] as? Data,
        let packet = value.pt_hexString,
        let per = notification.userInfo?[Notification.BLEKey.peripheral] as? CBPeripheral,
        PTConnectManager.shared().currentPer == per
        else { return }
```

The code of above can work, but hard to read, is there some solution to be friendly? thanks.

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. Not sure about the last part of your guard statement though. What part of the assignment to `PTConnectManager.shared().currentPer` might fail?

Comment: swift3 using , replace where

Comment: Oh, right. Still not use to that change. Frankly I preferred the `where` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm not fond of multiple  clauses wrapped up in a single `guard` statement. There is nothing gained, in my view, over multiple `guard` statements:

```
guard let value = notification.userInfo?[Notification.BLEKey.value] as? Data 
    else {return}
guard let packet = value.pt_hexString 
    else {return}
guard let per = notification.userInfo?[Notification.BLEKey.peripheral] as? CBPeripheral 
    else {return}
// ... and so on
```

I find that much more legible: it's like a series of doors that the data must get through.

Comment: Personal taste I guess. I have no problem with multi-part guard or `if let` statements, and prefer them to your version (No offense, whatever you find easier to read.)